# Android webview and certs on 4.4.2

Tags: android, webview, certificate

I am trying to get client Samsung tablet to work with site requiring client devices to have cert. I can get it working on tablets with 5.0+ because webview has onReceivedClientCertRequest. So I can use that to then load the cert and the key.

But I am having problems on tablets running 4.4.2 because that onReceivedClientCertRequest function is for 5+. When I run on 4.4.2 my concern is that the logger shows:

> '12-23 12:46:07.541 20804-20804/com.example.ssltest I/chromium:
>   [INFO:aw_content_browser_client.cc(349)] Client certificate request
>   from  rejected. (Client certificates not supported in
>   WebView)'

...is is true that I can't use webview on tablets running<5 if site requires client cert?

If not true, can someone help me on how to do it?

Comment: Do you need this for testing purposes or for production code?

Comment: production code

Answer (score 0):

You can install user certificates on a 4.4.2 tablet. This would not be the right solution for production code (for production you would usually have a trusted cert anyways), but is good for testing a site which does not have a trusted cert.

To do this:

1. Download the cert file to the phone.
2. In the Settings go to the security tab. In it under **Credential storage** find **Install from SD card**:

[image: Security settings]

3. Select the file you downloaded:

[image: Select file]

4. You need to install a PIN/Password if you don't already have one.

Comment: I can install the cert, it is a .p12 but not CA signed. Is that the problem maybe?