# Android Studio webview and certificates

Tags: android, ssl, webview, certificate, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using the webview in Android Studio to try and bring up a website that requires the client devices (Samsung tablets running 4.4.2 in this case) to have certificates. This is my last attempt to try and get this working before trying something else.

I have asked the question here with no real answers:

[Android webview and certs on 4.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306089/android-webview-and-certs-on-4-4-2)

It appears the webview control on 4.4.2 doesn't support certs  (Client certificates not supported in WebView)..from the log window.

Not sure if other people can get this working. I've read and tried many things from different posts, notably this:

http://fulltechie.blogspot.ca/2010/07/android-mutual-authentication-using.html

But still...the same 'certs not supported in webview'.

So questions:

Does anybody actually successfully have client certs working with webview on 4.4.2?

If so, please help with code or what might be wrong. Maybe because the cert is user-signed not CA?

Also, I know there is the overrideSSl method available but that is not being triggered. If I just open Chrome on the tablet and goto the link, it pops up with the cert requirements. But in application, webview just shows '403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.' Is that because of how the cert is setup on the server? Can it be configured differently so I can catch the SSLerror and then allow the handler to proceed?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Been trying to get this to work for way too long now.

Comment: I do not know if webview supports authtentication with client certificates, but if the log window shows that message then I think you have the answer. Since is a restricted browser I'm not surprised. For your doubts about if the CA is well configured I deduce that you do not currently have a production website  to embed. Then, why you want to use a webview instead of build a native component with a REST api?

Comment: 1) the website is already built and 2) we want to add functionality to interact with the website (if on certain pages, call functions with the main android app to do certain things). So with the webview, we can watch which pages the user is going to, and invoke whatever functionality we need which we need the main app to do.

Comment: Then the need of funcionality in webview is clear. I cant guess a workaround. You would need also to distribute the client certificates to each device and install it in system keystore